# React Material UI Box text goes out of the div

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to build a simple react page, but I got stuck at the very beginning: my text goes out of the box and I don't understand why is it happening.

Could somebody have a look at my styles? [Picture with the inherited styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/738o8.jpg)

If I delete the `whiteSpace="nowrap"`, the text is going way below.
My goal is to have the  and the text at the bottom of the picture. 
Does somebody know where the problem might be? Thanks very much in advance!

**HeaderMui.js**

```
 const url = process.env.PUBLIC_URL  + "/img/castle.jpg";
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme => ({
```

header: {
    height: "57vh",
  background: `url(${url})`,
  backgroundSize: "cover",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "center",
  backgroundPosition: "center center",
  backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
  flexGrow: 1,
},

headerText: {
  textAlign: "left",
  fontSize: 20,
  lineHeight: 20,
  boxSizing: "border-box",
  display: 'inline-block',
  alignItems: "center",
  textAlign:"center"
},
textWrapper: {

```
display: "block",
paddingRight: 15,
paddingLeft: 15,
alignItems: "center"
```

},

}

```
)));

function HeaderMui() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Box className={classes.header} flexWrap="nowrap">
    <Box className={classes.textWrapper} width="100%" flexWrap="nowrap">
    <h2 >Hogwarts Online</h2>
      < Box component="span" className={classes.headerText} display="inline-block" flexWrap="wrap" whiteSpace="nowrap"> Hogwarts Online is the first platform out there for the wizards far away from Hogwarts. Experience the power of British magical education while still working muggle job. All you need is a magic wand and to be a proved wizard!</Box>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
export default HeaderMui;
```

**App.js**

`function App(){

const greaterThanSm = useMediaQuery(theme => theme.breakpoints.up("sm"));
const greaterThanMd = useMediaQuery(theme => theme.breakpoints.up("md"));
    return (
        <>
      <Hidden only="xs">
        <AppbarMui />
      </Hidden>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid
          item
          xs={12}
          md={7}
          lg={12}
        >
        <HeaderMui />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;`

Comment: Please share your code in codesandbox with a reproduction of this issue

Comment: @rotimi-best Here it is [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-rhodes-25fou?file=/src/components/AppbarMui)

Comment: You have an error with in your sandbox. Your files in the component folder are without `.js`

Comment: thank you for pointing that out, now it is corrected

Answer (score 1):

Herminne.

I think the problem that you've faced is because of `boxSizing: "border-box",` in **headerText** class definitely.

Please check this docs, https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp

`box-sizing` allows us to have the content in the specific element's total width and height. That's why if the width + padding + margin of the content is bigger than the parent element's width, the content would be going outside of the parent's area.

Hopefully, this would be helpful. :)

Comment: Kevin, thank you for your answer. I deleted the boxSizing, and, sadly, nothing has changed. I guess the problem is in the very large div (it is seen on the attached picture)

Comment: Hmm, you need to adjust the `width` style in the parent element of span by using `width: fit-content`. Can you attach another picture that shows the parent element of the **span** element as in the element inspector?